# Does a porous medium have to be charged in order for the fluid to establish the streaming potential?

Tags: electrolysis

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_current), I read:

> Adjacent to the channel walls, the charge-neutrality of the liquid is
> violated due to the presence of the electrical double layer: a thin
> layer of counterions attracted by the charged surface.    The transport of counterions along with the pressure-driven fluid flow gives rise to a net charge transport: the streaming current.

But when I asked the chat.openai, it said

> No, a porous medium does not necessarily have to be charged to
> establish streaming potential. Streaming potential can arise in a
> porous medium when a fluid flows through it, and there is a pressure
> gradient across the medium. This can create a charge separation in the
> pore fluid due to the movement of ions, resulting in an electric
> potential difference across the medium. The zeta potential, which is
> the potential difference between the surface of the porous medium and
> the bulk fluid, can influence the magnitude and direction of the
> streaming potential. However, even in the absence of a zeta potential,
> a pressure-driven flow can induce a streaming potential in the pore
> fluid.

So, now I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Please be more precise ! You start by speaking of "Adjacent to the channel walls" . Well ! Which channel ? Which walls ? What is adjacent ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_layer_(surface_science)  In surface science, a double layer (DL, also called an electrical double layer, EDL) is a structure that appears on the surface of an object when it is exposed to a fluid. The object might be a solid particle, a gas bubble, a liquid droplet, or a porous body.

Comment: in the specific case of my question it is the walls of the porous body that is saturated by the fluid

Comment: Is chat.openai a brother of chatGPT?

Comment: You have asked everyone, what do the library and the books there say?

Comment: @AChem they told me to post my question here